# Is there a way to share a gitlab rep using a link

Tags: gitlab, repository

I need to share my repository with someone is there a way to share it via link? (like you can wit google docs for example)

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to a public repository, you can simply use the URL

> https://gitlab.com/user/repo

If the repository is private, you will need to [add them as a project member](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/members/) which would automatically send an email to the individual.